# Android app Java NullPointerException in OnClick

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have got stuck for the past few days trying to debug a very weird Java NullPointerException in one of my OnLickListener events (I honestly don't know which) inside my Android application.

My app is published in the Play Store and has Firebase crash reporting enabled, which is the source of any details I have on the bug, Firebase has reported the following stack trace:

```
Exception java.lang.NullPointerException:

package.name.activity.QuoteList$1.onClick (QuoteList.java)
android.view.View.performClick (View.java:4439)
android.widget.ImageButton.performClick (ImageButton.java:105)
android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:18395)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:725)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:92)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:176)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5317)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:511)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1102)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:869)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (NativeStart.java)
```

I have renamed the app's package name to "package.name" in the stack trace for privacy reasons.

The issue has occurred more than 50 times to different users, but I've noticed it only occurs in Android 4.2.2 on API 17 version, the rest of my users using other Android versions seem unaffected.

As you can see in the stack trace, it doesn't mention any specific line in QuoteList.java but only hints at QuoteList$1 but I fail to understand what $1 means here, please explain that to me.

Here is the code where I have the 2 listeners:

```
btn_expand.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (adapter.isExpand()) {
            adapter.setExpand(false);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            btn_expand.setImageResource(R.drawable.actionbar_ic_resize);
            btn_expand.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        } else {
            adapter.setExpand(true);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            btn_expand.setImageResource(R.drawable.actionbar_ic_resize_pressed);
            btn_expand.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        }
    }
});

btn_logo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

        startActivity(i);
        QuoteList.this.finish();
    }
});
```

I hope someone can help me fix this issue, thank you for your help.

Comment: QuoteList$1 is the name of the anonymous class that implements OnClickListener. name of the anonymous class sounds funny, but it is

Comment: So is it the first (1) anonymous class that implements OnClickListener in QuoteList? Because I have 2 in the QuoteList class file.

Comment: I don't know, I'm not sure if we should trust the number in the name to be in the same order as they appear in the code

Comment: anyway, if you posted the code where you set these listener it wouldn't hurt

Comment: Of course, I have added the 2 suspects to the question, please take a look there.

Comment: hum, adapter or btn_expand might be null? can you reproduce the crash?

Comment: running an emulator on that API level should reproduce the crash

Comment: Hum... btn_expand is initialized and set just before the listener, but adapter is just initialized in this context but later set to a new QuoteAdapter instance in an AsyncTask class in the onPostExecute method, could that be the issue? I will try the app in an Android 4.2 emulator to see what happens, takes some time.

Comment: it could be maybe one can click the view before the asynctask has finished and adapter is null

Comment: I guess so, but why does the error only manifest in API 17 devices? That seems weird to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! the problem was that, in some cases, the first `OnClickListener` was called (by a button) before the `adapter` object was set in `onPostExecute()` while the listener was defined in `onCreate()` which is executed well before the AsyncTask is started. Causing a `NullPointerException` of course.

So the solution was to simply move the above `OnClickListener` listeners to `onPostExecute()` just after where `adapter` is set to a new Adapter object.

It is easy to overlook something like this when you start mixing an AsyncTask class inside an Activity class and you lose track of what's executed first. So I hope this answer helps someone in the future.